# Optimizing the execution time of python for loop containing dot product

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dot-product

I am looking for some help in optimizing the below code in terms of execution time:

```
S = np.zeros((k,k))
for i in range(n):
    comp1 = np.matrix(y[i] - np.dot(Hy[i], Mu0))
    comp2 = np.dot(comp1.transpose(), comp1)
    comp3 = np.dot(Hy[i].transpose, comp2)
    comp4 = np.dot(comp3, Hy[i]
    S = np.add(S, comp4)
S = np.add(S, np.identity(k)/10**6
```

Comment: Without a small test example, I'm not going to try to test or improve your code.  At the minimum tells us about the arrays, `y` and `Hy`.  If you have 3d arrays, (n, ...,...), you can use `np.matmul/@` to perform `dot` on the last 2 dimensions, treating the first, `n` as a `batch`.  Transposing, reshaping, and adding dimensions, and `squeeze` may be needed.  `np.einsum` also lets us work with multiple dimensions.

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj. My arrays are only 2D in shape.